# Queue_Classic: How to run the rake task automatically on Heroku without Procfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, queue

i need to know how to run the queue_classic (rake qc:work) rake task automatically on Heroku. I tried with Procfile, but i am using Bamboo and i get the next error: "Heroku push rejected, Procfile is not supported on the Bamboo stack"

any idea??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On heroku there is a addon viz heroku-scheduler, its free. Add this addon to your application. It will appear in your application addon lists, click it, and you will lead to worker dashboard where you can add job for example

```
 bundle exec rake task_name
```

and schedule the task.